# why Arduino Nano Atmega328P D9 & D10 GPIO Blowing while using PNP Transistor S8550?

Tags: arduino, inverter, pnp, wave, sine

I am trying to make an Simple Sinve Wave Inverter circuit using below Schmatic.

As soon as I connect this circuit D9 & D10 gets damaged. should I change the value of 100Ohm to 1K ? will that solve the problem?

Please guide.

[image]

Comment: Please check the datasheet of the BJT and find the current gain graph. Design such that voltage at base doesn’t exceed 5 and take resistor value according to the current gain curve.

Answer (score 2):

The voltage at the base of the PNPs will be about 10V and this voltage will be presented the Arduino's pins which is why they are getting damaged. Increasing the resistance of the 100 ohm resistors won't solve the problem.

This SE question:

[Switching 9V using a NPN transistor and an Arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/95089/switching-9v-using-a-npn-transistor-and-an-arduino)

shows a couple of different ways of using an NPN to switch a higher voltage from an Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

I think the transistors should be S8050 NPN types, and also E and C swapped (so the emitter is grounded).

Right now the E-B junctions are conducting the +12V to your MCU which will destroy the chip.